# Sharepoint custom aspx page can't connect to database

Tags: asp.net, database, sharepoint

I have created a custom aspx page within my Sharepoint site with a SQL Server connection to a database on that server to select data. When I view the page it works, but when another user tries to view it it gives the following error :

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Login failed for user 'GRINCOR\GuguK'.
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'GRINCOR\GuguK'.

Can someone give me a solution to this problem? I am using Sharepoint Services 3.0.

Comment: This has nothing to do with SharePoint as such - its a basic account/permissions problem. Really - the clue is in the very first sentence of the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see you can't login on your Database.

Login failed for user 'GRINCOR\GuguK'

This means that the user with Name Guguk can't login.

Comment: GUGUK could be either the actual user or a service account, you need to make sure which it is and enable that account to have access to the database, as its within sharepoint I'd make sure I was impersonating the user so that each user can customise their own content (even if its not a requirement now it will save you time later)

Comment: how do i enable access to the database i am using sql server 2008 , im still new to sharpoint

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're using Integrated security in your connection string and perhaps you should go with specified credentials instead of having to grant every user who might access the page with permissions in the database.

Comment: this is my current  connection string on my page how do i modify this for all users who access my sharepoint site in the company to view this page ? , 

            con = new SqlConnection("server=srvgmssapqas;database=hrportal2;Trusted_Connection=True");

Comment: If you only want to grant one account access to the database you specify that account in the connection string.
Data Source=srvgmssapqas;Initial Catalog=hrportal2;User Id=*username*;Password=*password*;

Comment: i want to grant access to this page to all users that access the sharpoint site with windows authentication

Comment: Then I suggest you create an account for db access and then specify that account in the connection string I provided above.

Answer (score 0):

I would do following:

1. Create an Active Directory Group with all users that should have access to the SharePoint Site
2. Add this Group to the SharePoint Site with appropriate privileges (Member)
3. Add this Group to the MS SQL Server database with appropriate privileges (db_writer?)

I have not tested but I think it should work. It also simplifies the management of the users because you have a central point where you manage users (Active Directory)

Answer (score 0):

Granting Access to a SharePoint page is completely different then granting access to a database.

For the sharepoint page, you have to modify user privileges under "people and groups".  Since you mentioned this is a completely custom aspx page, I'm assuming you have it in the _layouts folder in which anybody who has access to your sharepoint site already has permissions to view the page.

For your database, I agree with above.  Create a SQL user and use that user in the connection string to the database.  This way, no matter who logs into sharepoint they will be using your sql user as credentials for database information.