# How to add on users to my sql server 2008 database?

Tags: database, sharepoint

I have a sharepoint site with sql connection. I am able to view the info on the page but other sharepoint users in the company can't. How can I add them on as users to my database? My connection string on my page is as follows :

```
con = new SqlConnection("server=srvgmssapqas;database=hrportal2;Trusted_Connection=True");
```

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787046/sharepoint-custom-aspx-page-with-database-connection

Answer (score 1):

No, you should **not** give all the company users permissions to access the database.

The `Trusted_Connection=True` piece of the connection string means that **account used by SharePoint's application pool is used to access the database**.

Read the [Account permissions and security settings (Office SharePoint Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863.aspx) article for more information.

Answer (score -1):

you dont, you make a view and connect the users to that view, not the basic db.

but if you saying that each user can connect to the sql server 2008 in a single pc using his sql server mangmt stdio then,

on that one cpu having the db, you need to add those who can connect to your sql server by

right click security>  logins >>new login >> search for user and select it >> if the user is no your network the computer name should appear in the search.

or

just enable the sa account and change the password.

be sure that sql server08 is installed with "MIXED MODE AUTHENTICATION" or else this will not work. "INSTALL ANOTHER INSTANCE WITH OPTION "botn windows and mixed mode authentication"